# How to extract a value (in a specific row and column) from a file and assign it to a new variable

Tags: linux

I have a text file "a.txt", it is a 3X4 matrix, the structure is as follows:

```
1 apple 50 Mary
2 banana 40 Lily
5 orange 34 Jack
```

I want to extract the value "40" (Row 2, Col 3) and assign it to a new variable called "price".

I tried this:

```
awk 'NR == 2 {print $3}' a.txt > price
echo "$price"
```

But why the result is:

```
0
```

How can I solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/varassignment.html

Comment: tldp is not a good ressource, check my response and my link ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To store the output of a command in a variable, use :

```
variable=$( commandFooBar )
```

Check [HERE](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ#BashFAQ.2F002.How_can_I_store_the_return_value_and.2For_output_of_a_command_in_a_variable.3F)

Comment: Thank you. It works. `price=$(awk 'NR == 2 {print $3}' a.txt); echo $price`

Comment: Yes, but _without_ the spaces around `=`

Comment: O, yes! Thank you. Otherwise, the price will be detected as a command

Comment: You resource is actually better than tldp. Thanks again! @Gilles Quenot

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing up two different shell operators.

The `>` redirect, will redirect output to a file. So to get your example to work, you could use:

```
awk 'NR == 2 {print $3}' a.txt > price
cat price   # display contents of file named price
```

The `$` refers to a variable, so to get your `echo` to print out the variable, you would first have to set it from the output of the previous. Like so:

```
price=$(awk 'NR == 2 {print $3}' a.txt)
echo "$price"
```

Comment: Great! Really helpful! Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

The value isn't stored in variable but stored in a file named 'price'. Hence echo will not show a value.
Try `vim price`.

Comment: How will this help the OP assign a value to a variable?